# Тип для события input

Tags: javascript, typescript

Имею код:

```typescript
// slider имеет тип HTMLInputElement

slider.addEventListener('input', (e: InputEvent) =>
{
    video.playbackRate = parseFloat(e.target.value);
});
```

Можете объяснить, почему я получаю ошибки подобного плана:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Должно ли это быть таким?

```typescript
slider.addEventListener('input', ({ target }: Event) =>
{
    if (target === null)
    {
        return;
    }

    video.playbackRate = parseFloat((target as HTMLInputElement).value);
});
```

Comment: Так там вроде просто [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event#event_type), а не `InputEvent`

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вы его применяете не к `input` или `textarea`. [В документации сказано](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event):

> For `<textarea>` and `<input>` elements that accept text input (type=text, type=tel, etc.), the interface is InputEvent; for others, the interface is Event

Т.е. если применено именно к `textarea` или `input` типа текст, телефонный номер и т.д., то только для них типа `InputEvent`, для всех остальных - Event

Comment: У меня `type="slider"`.

Comment: @OliverPatterson А что за тип `slider`? Может вы хотели `range`?

Comment: Точно, перепутал, когда писал комментарий.

Comment: @OliverPatterson Ну даже если так, так же нет ввода текста, там просто ползунок перемещается, потому вам нужен тип `Event`

Comment: Я в конце вопроса добавил код, который больше не показывает ошибки, я правильно написал?

Comment: @OliverPatterson Да, вроде всё правильно написано

Comment: Спасибо огромное) Пытаюсь вникнуть в мир TypeScript, давно хотел)

Comment: @OliverPatterson Обращайтесь) Это очень полезно)